# How to add column names dynamically in HTML table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table with One header and two buttons. One button with name 3days and other with name 7 for week.Now in my current table when I am clicking on button 3 then 3 columns are getting added. Now I want the header of those columns also and this should be dynamically as like the column cells are getting added. Also I need the column header names to be based on first digit of date like 13,14,15 etc..

Here is the fiddle..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6TZt/1/)

Here is the jQuery code..

```
$(function () {
$("button").click(function (e) {
    var cols = $(this).val();

    // You'll want to do something here to get the column data
    var data = $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>"));
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        data.append($("<td>Col " + + "</td>"));
    }

    $("table").show();
    $("#clear").show();
    $("#table table tbody").html("").append(data);
});

$("#clear").click(function () {
   $("table").hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

Please help me..

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/X6TZt/15/

Comment: Its with different requirement

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Yes its correct ,one more thing that i need is column names should be in ascending order of dates like 13,14,15,16 etc,how to do it..